# List every permutations of iterable

Tags: python, permutation

```
from itertools import permutations
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
x = permutations (l, 3)
```

I get the following :

```
(0, 1, 2) , (0, 1, 3), ...., (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 3), (0,2,4),...., (4, 3, 0), (4, 3, 1),
(4, 3, 2)
```

Which is what was expected.
But what i need is :

```
(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), ...., (0, 0, 4), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)........
```

How to achieve this ?

Comment: You did not explain what the result should contain. But check the other functions in itertools to see if one fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a permutation *with replacement*, or a product, but `itertool`'s `permutations` produces permutations without replacement. You can calculate the product yourself:

```
[(x,y,z) for x in l for y in l for z in l]
#[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), (0, 1, 0), ...
```

Or use the namesake function from `itertools`:

```
list(itertools.product(l,repeat=3))
# [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), (0, 1, 0),...
```

The latter approach is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `product` , not using `permutations`, from `itertools` module like this example:

```
from itertools import product

l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# Or:
# b = list(product(l, repeat=3))
b = list(product(l,l,l))
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), ..., (4, 4, 1), (4, 4, 2), (4, 4, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need product and not permutation

```
from itertools import product
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = list(product(l, repeat=3))
```